# The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required with important libs

Tags: 12.04, apt

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libopenal1:i386 libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386 libgconf-2-4:i386 libatk1.0-0:i386
  libstdc++5:i386 libpam-winbind ttf-umefont gedit-common
  libgtksourceview-3.0-0 libxcomposite1:i386 libgail18:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386
  libv4l-0:i386 libqt4-qt3support:i386 libroken18-heimdal:i386
  libunistring0:i386 wine1.4-amd64 libcupsimage2:i386 libgphoto2-port0:i386
  libidn11:i386 libnss3:i386 gir1.2-peas-1.0 libcaca0:i386 gtk2-engines:i386
  libgudev-1.0-0:i386 libcairo-gobject2:i386 libavc1394-0:i386
  linux-headers-3.2.0-52-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-52 wine1.4 libaio1:i386
  libsane:i386 odbcinst1debian2:i386 libqt4-test:i386 libqt4-designer:i386
  libsdl-mixer1.2:i386 libcap2:i386 libproxy1:i386 ibus-gtk:i386
  libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 python-zeitgeist libtdb1:i386 libasn1-8-heimdal:i386
  libspeex1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libgomp1:i386 libzeitgeist-1.0-1
  libcapi20-3:i386 libibus-1.0-0:i386 libcairo2:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386
  libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 libcanberra0:i386 zeitgeist-datahub
  gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 zeitgeist libwavpack1:i386 libqt4-opengl:i386
  libsoup-gnome2.4-1:i386 libv4lconvert0:i386 gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386
  nvidia-settings-304 librsvg2-common:i386 libiec61883-0:i386 wine1.4-common
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libsdl-image1.2:i386 wine-gecko1.4
  wine-gecko1.4:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386
  libsdl1.2debian:i386 libxaw7:i386 libgdbm3:i386 winetricks libcurl3:i386
  libpeas-common libxinerama1:i386 libesd0:i386 libmikmod2:i386 libgif4:i386
  gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 libreadline6:i386 libxft2:i386
  libgtksourceview-3.0-common libcroco3:i386 libpulse-mainloop-glib0:i386
  libaa1:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libao4:i386 libxmu6:i386
  libcanberra-gtk0:i386 libvorbisfile3:i386 esound-common language-pack-kde-en
  libxpm4:i386 libqt4-svg:i386 libusb-0.1-4:i386 libgail-common:i386
  libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libraw1394-11:i386 libnspr4:i386 libshout3:i386
  libdv4:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 kde-l10n-engb wine1.4-i386:i386
  gstreamer0.10-x:i386 libgettextpo0:i386 libgd2-xpm:i386
  libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libsdl-net1.2:i386 libjasper1:i386
  libgnome-keyring0:i386 zeitgeist-core libxtst6:i386 gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386
  libtag1c2a:i386 librsvg2-2:i386 libssl0.9.8:i386 libmpg123-0
  libmpg123-0:i386 libmad0:i386 libpeas-1.0-0 libsasl2-2:i386
  gtk2-engines-oxygen:i386 xaw3dg:i386 libpango1.0-0:i386
  libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libpulsedsp:i386 winbind libxcb-render0:i386
  libodbc1:i386 libexif12:i386 libqt4-scripttools:i386 librtmp0:i386
  libxp6:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 language-pack-kde-en-base
  libsasl2-modules:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libltdl7:i386
  libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 glib-networking:i386 libsoup2.4-1:i386
  libgphoto2-2:i386 libtag1-vanilla:i386 libaudiofile1:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
```

if I run autoremove

```
v@gt680:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  esound-common gedit-common gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 glib-networking:i386 gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386 gstreamer0.10-x:i386 gtk2-engines:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 gtk2-engines-oxygen:i386 gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386
  ibus-gtk:i386 kde-l10n-engb language-pack-kde-en language-pack-kde-en-base libaa1:i386 libaio1:i386 libao4:i386 libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libatk1.0-0:i386 libaudiofile1:i386 libavc1394-0:i386 libcaca0:i386 libcairo-gobject2:i386
  libcairo2:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 libcanberra-gtk0:i386 libcanberra0:i386 libcap2:i386 libcapi20-3:i386 libcroco3:i386 libcupsimage2:i386 libcurl3:i386 libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 libdv4:i386 libesd0:i386 libexif12:i386
  libgail-common:i386 libgail18:i386 libgconf-2-4:i386 libgd2-xpm:i386 libgdbm3:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libgettextpo0:i386 libgif4:i386 libgnome-keyring0:i386 libgomp1:i386 libgphoto2-2:i386 libgphoto2-port0:i386
  libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libgtksourceview-3.0-0 libgtksourceview-3.0-common libgudev-1.0-0:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libibus-1.0-0:i386
  libidn11:i386 libiec61883-0:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libjasper1:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libltdl7:i386 libmad0:i386 libmikmod2:i386 libmpg123-0 libmpg123-0:i386 libnspr4:i386 libnss3:i386 libodbc1:i386
  libopenal1:i386 libpam-winbind libpango1.0-0:i386 libpeas-1.0-0 libpeas-common libpixman-1-0:i386 libproxy1:i386 libpulse-mainloop-glib0:i386 libpulsedsp:i386 libqt4-designer:i386 libqt4-opengl:i386 libqt4-qt3support:i386
  libqt4-scripttools:i386 libqt4-svg:i386 libqt4-test:i386 libraw1394-11:i386 libreadline6:i386 libroken18-heimdal:i386 librsvg2-2:i386 librsvg2-common:i386 librtmp0:i386 libsane:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386
  libsdl-image1.2:i386 libsdl-mixer1.2:i386 libsdl-net1.2:i386 libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386 libsdl1.2debian:i386 libshout3:i386 libsoup-gnome2.4-1:i386 libsoup2.4-1:i386 libspeex1:i386 libssl0.9.8:i386 libstdc++5:i386 libtag1-vanilla:i386
  libtag1c2a:i386 libtdb1:i386 libunistring0:i386 libusb-0.1-4:i386 libv4l-0:i386 libv4lconvert0:i386 libvorbisfile3:i386 libwavpack1:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libxaw7:i386 libxcb-render0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcomposite1:i386
  libxcursor1:i386 libxft2:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxmu6:i386 libxp6:i386 libxpm4:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxtst6:i386 libzeitgeist-1.0-1 linux-headers-3.2.0-52 linux-headers-3.2.0-52-generic nvidia-settings-304
  odbcinst1debian2:i386 python-zeitgeist ttf-umefont winbind wine-gecko1.4 wine-gecko1.4:i386 wine1.4 wine1.4-amd64 wine1.4-common wine1.4-i386:i386 winetricks xaw3dg:i386 zeitgeist zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 150 to remove and 288 not upgraded.
After this operation, 425 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
Abort.
```

but it seems that there are important libs here! why does apt-get want to delete them?

Comment: They are out of date

Comment: from the `info apt-get` pages, autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no longer needed.

Comment: I think that problem is about to upgrading because I gave command for upgrading but then I cut it with ctrl+c but apt-get things all upgrade is done these are old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Sorted. These are out of date or left over remnants from uninstalled programs or the like.

Basically they're useless

Comment: yes but it will delete almost whole ubuntu I just remove bluez and now it want to remove almost whole ubuntu that is anormal

Comment: This is nothing like "the whole of Ubuntu". It will tell you how many megabites of backages will be deleted if you run the command.I dont think apt would report important packages as ussless. You can wait to see if someone confirms my answer before doing it.

Comment: Libs are librarys (collections of files that serve a specific function, when you run a program it uses libs to perform its functions if no install programs depend on on a lib it is deemed useless by the package manager

Comment: The autoremove is removing old package versions that are still present on your system as a result of upgrades.  I notice you have linux-headers-3.2.0-52 on your system, but if you enter the command `uname -r` I imagine that you will find you are running a much newer version of linux.